# Appending to lists in a dataframe via a for loop in Python, why is it being appended to each row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with `area` and `price` columns and have created a new column of empty lists called `compList`.

I am using a for loop to populate the `compList` for each row with the prices of any other houses with the same `area` value.

The result I am looking for is for `data['compList']` to be `[]` for all `area` values apart from the first and last which both have an `area` of 1500, where the `compList` values should each have one value, `31000` and `30000` respectively. Instead I am getting `[30000, 31000]` for every `compList` value.

What is wrong with my code? Been racking my head for 2 hours trying to figure this out. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import collections

reqArea = 1200
area = [1500, 500, 1000, 2000, 2500, 1500]
price = [30000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 31000]

data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(area,price)), columns = ['area','price'])
data['compList'] = [[]]*len(data['area'])
```

At this stage my dataframe looks like this:

```py
   area  price compList
0  1500  30000       []
1   500  10000       []
2  1000  20000       []
3  2000  40000       []
4  2500  50000       []
5  1500  31000       []
```

Then I process it.

```
for i in range(len(data['area'])):

    sameArea = []
    sameArea = np.where(data['area'] == data['area'][i])[0]

    if len(sameArea)>1:
        for j in range(len(sameArea)):
            if sameArea[j] != i:
                data['compList'][i].append(data['price'][sameArea[j]])

    else:
        pass
```

At the end my dataframe looks like this:

```py
   area  price        compList
0  1500  30000  [31000, 30000]
1   500  10000  [31000, 30000]
2  1000  20000  [31000, 30000]
3  2000  40000  [31000, 30000]
4  2500  50000  [31000, 30000]
5  1500  31000  [31000, 30000]
```

Comment: If is well known (among Python users) that `[[]]*n` make a list with `n` references to the **same** list.  Modify one of those references, and you end up modifying them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[]]*n is n references to the same object. Once you append `data['compList'][i].append(data['price'][sameArea[j]])` you are basically appending to the elements of your `compList` column (which are essentially one object). Try this:

```
reqArea = 1200

area = [1500, 500, 1000, 2000, 2500, 1500]

price = [30000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 31000]

data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(area,price)), columns = ['area','price'])

data['compList'] = np.empty((len(data), 0)).tolist()
```

Output using the rest of your code is:

```
   area  price compList
0  1500  30000  [31000]
1   500  10000       []
2  1000  20000       []
3  2000  40000       []
4  2500  50000       []
5  1500  31000  [30000]
```

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver. Why does this work while data['compList'] = [[]]*len(data['area']) doesnt?

Edit: Just saw @hpaulj 's response to my post. Thanks for your help!